# Math.random() in Javascript returning a value out of expected range

Tags: javascript

I can't wrap my head around this issue. I have a simple javascript code and I'm trying to generate a coordinate between 0 and 400. I have the following code:

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = imageSrc;

random = Math.random() * (leftSide.offsetHeight - image.height + 1);
image.style.top = Math.floor(random) + "px";

random = Math.random() * (leftSide.offsetWidth - image.width + 1);
image.style.left = Math.floor(random) + "px";

theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
//leftSide.offsetWidth and leftSide.offsetHeight are always 500
//image.height and image.width are always 100
```

I'm still seeing things going out of the borders so when I debug this code I found that the random variable is sometimes out of the expected range of (0, 401]. For example, at one point when debugging this I got a value of 468.

Any ideas?

Comment: *image.height and image.width are always 100*. After the image is loaded, yes, but you're not waiting for that. Also note that you should use your `theLeftSide` variable instead of relying on internal browser id resolution by using `leftSide`.

Comment: That's an interesting point, and it would explain why I sometimes get some value between 0 and 500 instead. How can I guarantee that the image is fully loaded before retrieving the values image.height and image.width?

Comment: Bind to the `load` event. There is a lot of information about achieving that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works when replacing image.height and image.width with 100 so it's like you said the image wasn't fully loaded.